# Puzzling about how computeIfAbsent works to update duplicate key->list value pair

Tags: java, collections

From this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-duplicate-keys),
computeIfAbsent is used to create and update the value list, but how is it achieved?

Here for

```
map.computeIfAbsent("key1", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("value2");
```

I was expecting no updates since key1 exist, however it ends up adding "value2" to the value list

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent("key1", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("value1");
map.computeIfAbsent("key1", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("value2");

assertThat(map.get("key1").get(0)).isEqualTo("value1");
assertThat(map.get("key1").get(1)).isEqualTo("value2");
```

Comment: If there is already a value (in this case a list) for that key in the map, it is returned, and you add an element to it.

Comment: The value corresponding to "key1" is an ArrayList.  Adding to that ArrayList doesn’t change the Map in any way:  "key1" still points to the same ArrayList object.

Comment: Ah I was not very careful, misread the parathesis and thought .add is part of the mapping function :(.  It is clear to me now.

Comment: @khlewood *If there is already a value (in this case a list) for that key in the map, it is returned..*  Which includes the value just added.  So it `always` returns a value.